# Linux script that runs a java server through nodejs?

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a java program that starts a TCP/IP game server.

I have an angular application that speaks with an express node.js server to start/stop the game server.

When the button start is clicked the following operation is performed in the nodejs server:

```
shell.exec('/web/starter.sh');
```

And this is my script:

```
:set fileformat=unix
#!/bin/sh
screen -RD server -X quit;
screen -dmS server;
cd ~/cadesim-monomer; 
java -jar CadeServerEngine.jar;
```

It works, it starts the server. But whenever I click start again, it doesn't restart the server as it should. It should kill the screen and restart?

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the server commands aren't running inside the detached screen session. They are running after both of the screen commands.

To run a command in detached screen session for this example would need to use:

```
screen -dmS server sh -c "cd ~/cadesim-monomer; java -jar CadeServerEngine.jar"
```

Or you can put the server and its setup in its own shell file and that file would have a similar appearance to a daemontools run script. And then you would have a command like:

```
screen -dmS server ./server.sh
```

Also the shebang line should be the first line in the file. The script just happens to work because the shell is the default interpreter. It produces the error `line 1: :set: command not found`. The VIM mode setting should occur in a comment on the second line.